# How to return data from Public class to MDIChild

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, mdichild

how to send data value from public class to mdichild active on vb.net

here is the class 
and i have windowsform called frmAkun

when i set frmAkun to mdichild, i call the class but can't return value to FrmAkun back

but if i set frmAkun as WindowsForm not mdichild the function is worked normaly

```
Public Class classAkun

 Public Sub cariBalance(ByVal textnode As String)

        Dim MyCmdA As New OdbcCommand
        Dim MyRederA As OdbcDataReader
        Dim openD, openC As String
        Dim lastD, lastC As String
        Dim noAkun As String
        Dim classi As String

        noAkun = Left(textnode, 6)


        MyCmdA.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM daftarakun WHERE NoAkun = '" & noAkun & "'"
        MyCmdA = New OdbcCommand(MyCmdA.CommandText, MyCn)
        MyRederA = MyCmdA.ExecuteReader

        If MyRederA.Read Then

            openD = MyRederA.Item("OpBalanceD")
            lastD = MyRederA.Item("LastBalanceD")

            openC = MyRederA.Item("OpBalanceC")
            lastC = MyRederA.Item("LastBalanceC")

            classi = MyRederA.Item("Klasifikasi")

            If classi = "ASSET" Or classi = "EXPENSE" Then

                If openC = 0 Then
                    frmAkun.OpBalance.Text = openD
                end if
end sub

end class
```

"frmAkun.OpBalance.Text = openD " can't send to frmakun when frmakun is mdichild active

it's sent when frmAkun is not mdichild

thx

Comment: Why use a sub when you can use a function? Convert your sub to a function that returns the OpenD as a string (or an empty string if it's not 0) and call it from the form

Comment: oo ok sir i'll try it first

Comment: @Irvanln - please accept Zohar's anwser if this solved your issue

Answer (score 2):

Why use a sub when you can use a function? Convert your sub to a function that returns the OpenD as a string (or an empty string if it's not 0) and call it from the form